# How to edit a file from a script using a loop instead of find and replace with sed?

Tags: scripting

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
#!/bin/bash
Update=$1

if [$Update == Value] 
then
    NewValue= $Update
    vi %s/Value/$NewValue/g > Updatedfile
fi
exit 0
```

Is there a way to utilize `vi` commands within a script? My thoughts are that some type of piping would do this?

Comment: Ahh, I was thinking sed, though did not want to assume that was the only command or technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `vi` commands in a stript: `sed` — **s**tream **ed**itor, is a member of the `vi` family (`ed`, `vi`, `sed`). It is used to edit streams of data passed via pipes, so just what you need. It also uses same commands as `vi`.

e.g.
To process standard in and put result in `Updatedfile`

```
sed -e "s/Value/$NewValue/g" > Updatedfile
```

see also `-i` option, to edit **i**n-place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Richard, you answer was helpful, though I was more concerned on how to use a loop statement, this initially solves the problem of using sed.